# Get Data From Logged In User On Random Websites

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is possible to get data from the users browser, like all of his facebook messages, and something like that. Or downloading html where user is logged in on some random webiste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't due to Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically a browser plugin could be used to harvest information like that to some extent. The user would have to consent to it and install the plugin though.

I hope you're not thinking of doing anything naughty...